# Data and API links should be visible in the footer

Tags: discussion, design, footer

The [new footer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/27/new-stack-overflow-footer-pages-launch-today/) looks nice and elegant, and it removes a large number of links to Stack Exchange sites that are already promotes at the "Hot Network Questions" section on each page.

However - the "other" category hides some important links:

[image: new footer on meta, with the "other" link highlighted]
[image: awesome links that are hidden]

I think the Apps, API, and Data links should be visible by default.
**These links promote open data and should be more accessible.** They should invite and encourage people to use them, even when the people don't know they exist. I think it is natural to look for "Data" or "API" in the footers of sites.

Stack Overflow users are highly technical, and are exactly the people who *will* use the API, query the Data, or write Apps - but these links are hidden on Stack Overflow, while still being visible on all other sites.

<sub>Also, in general, I believe *"other"* or *"misc."* should never be used when categorizing items - it becomes a garbage category where everything fits - but that's beside the point.</sub>

Comment: *I believe "other" or "misc." should never be used when categorizing items* - I **wholeheartedly agree** with this notion.

Comment: Not really sure what the benefit of having these visible all the time is, I'm not sure they're links that are used so often.

Comment: @DavidG - I doubt any of the footer links are used "often" - footers aren't  used for navigation. You only have to click it once, or even just see to know that there is an API, and there is data you can use - this is already a benefit. Currently the APIs are hidden, which is a shame because Stack Overflow has a culture of openness.

Comment: Interestingly, Ctrl-F for 'API' on this page still finds 'API' hidden behind that 'other' link, but it's not at all obvious where it actually is because it doesn't make itself appear when selected.

Comment: You mean everyone doesn't just type in `api.hostname.com` if they're looking for an API? :)